# how can I get data of $scope.selAppt from bookingToolCtrl into reasonDialogCtrl?

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in Angularjs and working on some else project.
how can I get data of $scope.selAppt from bookingToolCtrl into reasonDialogCtrl?

```js
(function () {
    app = angular.module('bookingToolApp', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'isteven-multi-select', 'angucomplete-alt', 'ngTable', 'dialogs.main', 'ngMap', 'BookingToolServices', 'BookingToolDirectives']);

    app.run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('/dialogs/reason.html', '<div class="modal-header"> <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Reserve Service {{selAppt.selected.eventid}}</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><ng-form name="nameDialog" novalidate role="form"><div class="form-group input-group-lg" ng-class="{true: \'has-error\'}[nameDialog.username.$dirty && nameDialog.username.$invalid]">   <label class="control-label" for="course">Reason:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reason" id="reason" ng-model="reason" ng-keyup="hitEnter($event)" required>  <span class="help-block">Enter the reason for reserving this service.</span></div></ng-form></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="(nameDialog.$dirty && nameDialog.$invalid) || nameDialog.$pristine">Submit</button></div>');
    }]);

    app.controller('bookingToolCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', '$sce', 'NgTableParams', '$filter', '$compile', '$rootScope', 'loadingEventService', 'claimantLatLngEventService', 'dialogs', '$timeout', 'ngTableEventsChannel', function ($scope, dataService, $sce, NgTableParams, $filter, $compile, $rootScope, loadingEventService, claimantLatLngEventService, dialogs, $timeout, ngTableEventsChannel) {
    
    $scope.selAppt = {"selected": false};
    }]);
 
 app.controller('reasonDialogCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
        
    });
 
})();
```

I tried the following but it doesn’t work:

```js
app.controller('reasonDialogCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'data', 'dataService', '$controller','$rootScope', function ($scope, $modalInstance, data, dataService, $controller,$rootScope) {
        //-- Variables --//

        $scope.data = dataService.data;
        $scope.service = dataService;     

        var testCtrl1ViewModel = $controller('bookingToolCtrl');        
  alert(testCtrl1ViewModel.selAppt);
    }]);
```

$scope.selAppt get values when I select an appointment.

Comment: How are you opening `modal`, code please? Are you using `$modal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **bookingToolCtrl**

```
$scope.selAppt = {"selected": false};
dataService.data = $scope.selAppt  //... you missed this
```

and in **reasonDialogCtrl**

```
$scope.data = dataService.data;
```